# Исчезает фокус приложение и не только

Tags: windows, windows-10

(Возможно вопрос не по программированию, но я не знаю, где его ещё задать) Приветствую, с какого-то момента у меня началась проблема в windows. Когда у меня имеется приложение в фокусе, и я навожусь на панель задач, фокус пропадает. Ещё, если у меня открыто несколько вкладок приложения, то когда я пытаюсь выбрать одну из вкладок(не через alt + tab), то панелька открывается на секунду, и снова закрывается.

Comment: Создай ещё одного пользователя и поработай в нём. Проблема останется или нет?

Comment: Всмысле ещё одну учетную запись, или что-то другое?

Comment: Да, которая `net user /add`.